# Cannot load a saved '.h5' checkpoint file into a python app, when deploying into Heroku

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, tf.keras, docker-checkpoint

I have been trying to create a machine learning app using Python. In that case I need to import a pre-trained model stored as `checkpoint-1.111.h5` file in the repository. But I am unable to import that model when deploying the code into Heroku. The repository gets deployed successfully, but on opening the app it  shows

> Internal Server Error

The code for the `app.py` is as follows:

```
import re
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request

from keras.models import load_model
# Run this cell to mount your Google Drive.
#from google.colab import drive
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences




app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    best_model =  load_model('checkpoint-1.111.h5')
    data_int_t = pad_sequences([[1, 72, 19, 38], [], [], [], []],padding='pre', maxlen=(30-5))
    data_test = pad_sequences(data_int_t, padding='post', maxlen=(30))
    y_prob = best_model.predict(data_test)
    return str(x + y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

On opening the app I always obtain the result Internal server error.
The logs are as follows:

```
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982084+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/io_utils.py", line 186, in __init__
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982086+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.data = h5py.File(path, mode=mode)
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982088+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 394, in __init__
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982090+00:00 app[web.1]:     swmr=swmr)
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982092+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 170, in make_fid
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982094+00:00 app[web.1]:     fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982097+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982099+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982101+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 85, in h5py.h5f.open
2019-07-02T17:38:32.982110+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

Both the files `app.py` and `checkpoint-1.111.h5` are present in the same location of the repository. However the `checkpoint-1.111.h5` is actually a `git-lfs` file. But is that an issue? `keras.models.load_model` totally works in loading the `checkpoint-1.111.h5` file when I use the same code in Google Colab.

Comment: "Internal server error" doesn't tell us anything useful. It's a generic server-side error message. Please run `heroku logs` to review your server-side logs. They should contain more information.

Comment: You say your file is called `checkpoint.h5` but your code tries to open `checkpoint-1.111.h5`. Is that a typo? In any case, looking at your logs you should see something more helpful.

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. I have added the logs.

Comment: Assuming that file is included in your repo, this likely means your code is looking in the wrong place for it. You're just giving it a file name, not a path, so it will look in whatever the working directory happens to be. Where is that file in relation to the rest of your files?

Comment: Ah. Yes, that is an issue. I'll add an aswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the `checkpoint-1.111.h5` is actually a `git-lfs` file

Heroku [doesn't support Git LFS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-from-a-branch-besides-master) and unfortunately I don't know enough about TensorFlow or Keras to suggest an alternative solution. With its hard [limit on slug size](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size) and [ephermal filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) Heroku might not be a good fit for this application.